# CMake link shared library on Windows

Tags: windows, build, cmake

There are three files, (*m.c*,*m.h*, and **main.c*).

#### File *m.h*

```
// m.h
int m();
```

#### File *m.c*

```
// m.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "m.h"

int m(){
    printf("Hello,m!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

#### File *main.c*

```
// main.c
#include "m.h"
int main(){
    return m();
}
```

While I prefer a shared library (*m.dll*), I've made the [CMakeLists.txt](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#organization) file:

```
    PROJECT("app1")
    ADD_LIBRARY(m SHARED m.c)
    ADD_EXECUTABLE(myexe main.c)
    TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myexe m)
```

The CMake configuration is done and generated done. Opening app1.sln and building with Visual Studio, it crashes as

```
LNK1104:Can't open file "Debug\m.lib"
```

It only works as **STATIC** at `ADD_LIBRARY()`. Why doesn't it work on Windows?

If I got another shared library (*mylib.dll*), how could I invoke its functions in my main.c and CMakeLists.txt files?

Comment: `It always crashes` - **what** is crashed? CMake configuration step(`cmake.exe` call), build step (BTW, what tool do you use for build? Visual Studio? Make?) or running executable? What error message comes along with this crash?

Comment: The CMakeLists.txt works well on Ubuntu-14.04. **libm.so** generated.

Comment: @llorch Welcome to StackOverflow. With just a view modifications to your code you can make it happen. See my answer below.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There are differences between dynamic library linking on different platforms which also needs some additional code. The good news is, that CMake can help you with this. I found the following blog post by [Gernot Klingler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5206987/gernot-klingler) very useful:

- [Creating and using shared libraries with different compilers on different operating systems](http://gernotklingler.com/blog/creating-using-shared-libraries-different-compilers-different-operating-systems/)

In short you need some "export prefix" defined for whatever is declared in `m.h`. Otherwise the build process will not generate an "import library" for statically linking named `m.lib` (see also [`CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX.html)).

Here is your code with the modifications needed:

**m.h**

```
#include "m_exports.h"

int M_EXPORTS m();
```

**m.c**

```
#include "m.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int m(){
    printf("Hello,m!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

include(GenerateExportHeader)

PROJECT("app1")

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES("${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}")
ADD_LIBRARY(m SHARED m.c m.h m_exports.h)
GENERATE_EXPORT_HEADER(m           
    BASE_NAME m
    EXPORT_MACRO_NAME M_EXPORTS
    EXPORT_FILE_NAME m_exports.h
    STATIC_DEFINE SHARED_EXPORTS_BUILT_AS_STATIC)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(myexe main.c)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myexe m)
```

**Additional References**

- [GenerateExportHeader](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/GenerateExportHeader.html) macro
- [cmake and GenerateExportHeader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982144/cmake-and-generateexportheader)
- [How do I get CMake to create a dll and its matching lib file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614286/how-do-i-get-cmake-to-create-a-dll-and-its-matching-lib-file)
- MSDN: [Walkthrough: Creating and Using a Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636.aspx)

Comment: `CMAKE_IMPORT_LIBRARY_SUFFIX` helped. Thanks.

Comment: @Florian Does this mean I have to create multiple `xxx_exports.h` for every library if I have multiple shared libraries. Besides, what about static library with cmake on windows?

Answer (score 23):

Using [WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/prop_tgt/WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS.html) might help. See [an introductory article](https://blog.kitware.com/create-dlls-on-windows-without-declspec-using-new-cmake-export-all-feature/) for details. In short, invoke CMake like this:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=TRUE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=TRUE
```

Answer (score 8):

Add this in `CMakeLists.txt`.

```sh
if(MSVC)
    set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
    set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS TRUE)
endif()
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me give my two cents for the FLYPoPo's answer in case of Windows platform, not VC only. Same CMakeLists.txt:

```bash
if (WIN32)
    set (CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS TRUE)
    set (BUILD_SHARED_LIBS TRUE)
endif ()
```

This works fine for me.