# How to build static and shared library at the same time through cmake

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cmake

I am learning cmake on windows.
I read and run [this example](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/cmake-and-visual-studio/) so that I can build both static and shared libraries from one visual studio project.
I found this command:

```
add_library(math SHARED ${MATH_SOURCES} ${SIMPLE_FUNCTION_SOURCES} ${ADVANCED_FUNCTION_SOURCES})
```

According to my understanding, this command is building shared library. Also, from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152077/is-it-possible-to-get-cmake-to-build-both-a-static-and-shared-version-of-the-sam), if I want to build static and shared library, I have to do it by two projects.

So, why the first example I used can build both libraries from one Visual Studio project?

**Edit**
Thanks for `Florian`, the key point is in `MathExports.h`. To let people easier to see, I put the file here:

```
#ifndef MathExports_h
#define MathExports_h

#ifdef _WIN32
    #ifdef math_EXPORTS
        #define  MATH_EXPORT __declspec( dllexport )
    #else
        #define  MATH_EXPORT __declspec( dllimport )
    #endif
#else
    #define    MATH_EXPORT
#endif

#endif // MathExports_h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked example doesn't build a standalone static `math` library. It does have "exports" (see `MathExports.h`) and therefore it's generating an additional import `.lib` (which references the build shared library).

This import library is used when you are "linking" against the DLL.

You can use

```
dumpbin /symbols math.lib
```

to see the references in `math.lib` to `math.dll`.

**References**

- [Tools for inspecting .lib files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488809/tools-for-inspecting-lib-files)
- [Getting CMake to build shared library for MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37128555/getting-cmake-to-build-shared-library-for-msvc)
- [How does the Import Library work? Details?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3573475/how-does-the-import-library-work-details)
- [How do I build an import library (.lib) AND a DLL in Visual C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/584041/how-do-i-build-an-import-library-lib-and-a-dll-in-visual-c)