# C++ include library in Cmake project

Tags: c++, cmake

I am attempting to integrate a C++ library I downloaded into a new project using CMake.

I downloaded the library ("downloaded_library"), created the `build` folder, and inside of it ran `cmake ..` and `make`. These both ran successfully, and than I navigated to the build folder and ran ./example to run the example file that came with the library. This also was successful, and so I hoped to add it to another project.

I added this working project into the 'libraries' folder of the following directory structure:

```
project
  -libraries
      -downloaded_library
          -build
          -include
              -downloaded_lib
                  -downloaded_lib.h
          -src
          -examples
              -example.cpp
          -CMakeLists.txt
  -src
      -main.cpp
  -build
  -CMakeLists.txt
```

I hope to run the same code that ran in `example.cpp` in `main.cpp`, but I have been unable to get the import working. I navigate to the build folder and `cmake ..` runs successfully, but 'make' fails with an import error (fatal error on the include line, can't find the header file). This makes sense, as I didn't expect the same include line to work (I copy and pasted example.cpp to main.cpp), but I'm not sure what to make that.

```
fatal error: downloaded_lib/downloaded_lib.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include "downloaded_lib/downloaded_lib.h"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

In this situation, what should my CMakeLists.txt contain, and what should my `#include` contain to be able to use the contents of this library in `main.cpp` in the same way I can in `example.cpp`?

EDIT---
I changed the package names above for simplicity sake, but the repository of 'downloaded_library' is the following: https://github.com/siposcsaba89/socketcan-cpp.

My top level CMakeLists.txt looks like this:

```
# Minimum version of CMake required to build this project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Name of the project
project(projectname)

# Add all the source files needed to build the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

add_subdirectory(libraries/downloaded_library)

# Link the executable and the library together
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} downloaded_library)
```

Edit 2-- (Here I will use the original package name, socketcan-cpp).

Top level CMakeLists.txt:

```
# Minimum version of CMake required to build this project
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)

# Name of the project
project(socketcan_demo)

# Add all the source files needed to build the executable
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} src/main.cpp)

add_subdirectory("libraries/socketcan-cpp")

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "libraries/socketcan-cpp/include")
```

When running `make` I get this error:

```
fatal error: socketcan_cpp/socketcan_cpp_export.h: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <socketcan_cpp/socketcan_cpp_export.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

So the top level CMakeLists is able to find the header file located in  include, but that header file contains the line: `#include <socketcan_cpp/socketcan_cpp_export.h>` which references a file in a `gen` directory inside the `build` directory created by the library's CMakeLists.txt (https://github.com/siposcsaba89/socketcan-cpp/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt). And my top level package is unable to find it.

Comment: target_link_libraries?

Comment: right now I have `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} downloaded_library)` in my root CMakeLists.txt but it didn't seem to have helped.

Comment: You need to post a real MRE, ie. _everything_ necessary to reproduce your issue. Generally, when you have a problem and have not been able to solve it yourself, it is because (in part) you are unable to localize the problem correctly. If your project is open source, post a link to a git repo or something.

Comment: Ok, I updated the question to include the repository I downloaded, and the top level CMakeLists.txt. That is everything contained in this project.

Comment: So if the downloaded lib is indeed socketcan_cpp, I assume you're doing `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}` socketcan_cpp)` and not `target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} downloaded_library)`. This should already provide you with the required include directories, see https://github.com/siposcsaba89/socketcan-cpp/blob/5e328b7afe70b359a06f340ac7240ae36a544f5c/CMakeLists.txt#L50 Btw: The linked cmake command combined with `#include <socketcan_cpp/socketcan_cpp_export.h>` indicates that the library's git must be cloned into a dir `socketcan_cpp`, not to some dir of a different name.

Answer (score 0):

In order to include the header files from the downloaded library, you can add the following to the `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
find_library(downloaded_lib
             NAMES downloaded_lib
             HINTS "path to downloaded lib file")

if(NOT downloaded_lib)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "downloaded_lib not found!")
endif()

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_EXECUTABLE} PUBLIC "path to download_lib.h")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_EXECUTABLE} ${downloaded_lib})
```

This includes the directory where the header file is located in addition to the library file.

Comment: There is no lib file in the downloaded project... I got `CMake Error ... downloaded_lib not found!` when running `cmake ..`

Comment: If it's a header-only library it should be sufficient to only use the `target_include_directories()` function. In case there is no `downloaded_lib.so` or `downloaded_lib.a` file available.

Comment: I used `include_directories(libraries/downloaded_lib/include)`, but 'downloaded_lib.h' couldn't find the cmake export header file. Would using `target_include_directories` change that?

Comment: It should. See also the discussion here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16982144/cmake-and-generateexportheader). If it's really only a header file, you can also consider adding it to your other source files in the `CMakeLists.txt` file as an alternative.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, sorry, I am new to this. What would I put as the 'target' then? e.g. `target_include_directories(??? libraries/downloaded_lib/include)`

Comment: No problem. The target would be your project target or executable `${PROJECT_NAME}`.

Comment: Hm, that seems to have the same issue with finding the export header file located in `downloaded_lib/build/gen/downloaded_lib`.

Comment: Basically it seems like my project is able to find the header file using your solution, but that header file references a header file ending with _export.h which is created in the build directory when cmake is run. Is there a way I can watch the build directory for header references or is that bad practice?

Comment: The only other issue I can think of is, did you specify the absolute path to your files in the `CMakeLists.txt`?

Comment: I think so, I attached the CMakeLists and the one in the library, if you could look at those.

Comment: It looks like you specified the relative path. You can type `pwd` to get the absolute path. If you build the library with cmake, then you should also have a library file in the `build/lib` folder of your library. Likewise there should also be a `build/include` folder you can include.